# JS for and for...in with a string

Tags: javascript

I am making a loop that takes one character at a time from a string and gives the parts on its right and left as string slices.

When using for .. in, the right slice in the second iteration gives `''` when it should give `'c'`, although `i` is right in all iterations

```js
    var str = 'abc';
    for (var i in str)
      console.log(i + '/' + str[i] + '/' + str.slice(0, i) + '/' + str.slice(i + 1));
    /* output
    0/a//bc
    1/b/a/
    2/c/ab/
    */

// While it works normally with for

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i)
      console.log(i + '/' + str[i] + '/' + str.slice(0, i) + '/' + str.slice(i + 1));
    /* output
    0/a//bc
    1/b/a/c
    2/c/ab/
    */
```

Why does that happen? What's wrong if for...in when used with string?

Comment: for in loop is a very bad idea.... You are going to get things that you would not expect. Run in in the console of stackoverflow in chrome. You will see some other things inside the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `for ... in` loop, the values of `i` will be **strings**, not numbers. Property names are always strings<sup>*</sup>.

Thus, `i + 1` means `11` when `i` is `"1"`. The `.slice()` code will treat that as a number, and since there are only 3 characters in the string the result of that is an empty string.

In general, `for ... in` is not a good idea unless you *really* know that what you want to do is iterate through all enumerable properties of the object and its prototype chain. When iterating through the numbered properties of an array (or array-like object), an old-fashioned `for` loop over a range of numeric values is much safer and guarantees that you'll iterate in the expected order. (A `for ... in` loop does not guarantee order of iteration.) There's also `.forEach()` and the other `Array.prototype` methods for iteration.

* property names can also be Symbol instances in modern JavaScript, but that's clearly not the issue in this question.

Comment: Which means that `str.slice(+i + 1)` works - against all odds